# Extjs 4.0 MVC - how to close a view from within the controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, view, controller, extjs4

I have a simple example here with a modal window that is a 'view'.  I want to have a button within the window that does a window close, so the lazy user doesn't need to click the 'X' in top right.

My problem is I don't know how to reference the view from within the controller.  In the non-MVC world I would just do a 'window.close()' in the button handler.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

**View**

```
   Ext.define('AM.view.testwindow.window', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.TESTwindow',
    title: 'TEST Window',
    layout: 'border',
    width: 1000, height: 400,
    minimizable: true,
    maximizable: true,
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = [

        {xtype: 'gridpanel', region: 'center',    // grid in the window
        store: 'Equipments',
        columns: [
          { text: 'Equip ID',  dataIndex: 'EquipmentID' }
          , {  text: 'StationID',     dataIndex: 'StationID' }
        ],

        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',         // Grid's toolbar
            items: [
            {
                  xtype: 'button',              /* Close button to close the window */
                  text: 'Close Window',
                  itemId: 'btnTestClose'
              }
           ]
        }
      ]
    }
    ];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

**Controller**

```
  Ext.define('AM.controller.testwindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['Equipments', 'Stations'],
    models: ['Equipment'],
    views: ['testwindow.window', 'testwindow.Grid'],
    refs: [
    {        ref: 'TESTgrid',     selector: 'TESTgrid'   },
        {    ref: 'testwindow',   selector: 'testwindow'  }
    ],

    init: function () {

        this.control(
        {
            '#btnTestClose': {
                click: function (butt, e, options) {
                    alert('close handler!');
                    this.getTestwindowWindowView().close();   // this fails.   What should I do? ComponentQuery ?
                 }
            }

        }
        )
    }
}
);
```

Scope of 'this' from within Button handler

[image: Scope of 'this' from within Button handler]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ref` to the test window should match the alias `TESTwindow` (without the `widget` part), or maybe the long name `testwindow.window`:

```
refs: [
    {    ref: 'TESTgrid',     selector: 'TESTgrid'   },
    {    ref: 'TESTwindow',   selector: 'testwindow'  }
],
```

This will give you the autogenerated getter you need:

```
this.getTestwindow().close();
```

Getters are composed of `get` plus the reference selector with uppercase first letter.

Comment: Yes.... figured this out last night. I thought refs were just short-hand ways to access components but really they allow hard-wire references to components.   Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

```
refs: [
    {    ref: 'TESTgrid',     selector: 'TESTgrid'   },
    {    ref: 'win',   selector: 'testwindow'  }
],

Try this

this.getWin().close();


ready ok
```

Comment: Please [edit] in an explanation of why/how this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, the changes made to the code, if the code answers the question, etc.  The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting.

Comment: Please write some description/comment, so that user can understand.